# Firebase game matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, firebase

I'm trying to create player matching algorithm. So basically I expected it to work like that:

**Algorithm:**

1. Player creates game request specifying `bet` and `gameType`.
2. Server subscribes to following some query so from this list:

---

```
{
  'gameRequests': {
    '1': {
      createdAt: 1454777718074,
      uid: 123,
      bet: 10,
      gameType: 'nhl'
    },
    '2': {
      createdAt: 1454777718075,
      uid: 123,
      bet: 20,
      gameType: 'nhl'
    },
    '3': {
      createdAt: 1454777718076,
      uid: 321,
      bet: 10,
      gameType: 'nhl'
    },
  }
}
```

I would get requests with keys `'1'`, `'3'`.

---

3. Now i just delete children with keys `'1'`, `'3'` and create a game for them.

**What I have:**

So far I'm doing it by loading the whole `gameRequests` branch.

```
randomGamesRef.on('value', onGameRequestsUpdate)

function onGameRequestsUpdate (snapshot) {
    const gameRequests = snapshot.val()

    const pairs = _.chain(gameRequests)
      // Transform to array
      .values()

      // Group by sport and bet size
      .groupBy((req) => req.gameType + '+' + req.bet)

      // Map groups to pairs
      .map((group) => {
        return _.chain(group)
          .uniqBy('createdBy')
          .take(2)
          .value()
      })
      .filter((pairs) => pairs.length === 2)
      .value()

    // Now having this pairs I can delete them 
    // from the database and create new game
  }
```

But loading everything to memory every time doesn't seem like a good idea.

**Question:** How would you implemented it in Firebase?

Comment: Firebase is a database that stores JSON data so the implementation would be up to the developer. You could do what you are saying with the presented structure but the coding would depend on your development environment. What have you tried so far? Can you update your question with a brief example of your code?

Comment: What is `req.sport`? On what basis do you expect keys 1 and 3 to be matched? You JSON snippet doesn't have a `sport` property and all requests have the same  values.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry. That had to be `gameType` as in description. I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NoSQL you often end up modeling your data for the way you want to access it in your code. So instead of reading all game requests and then grouping them by `gameType` and `bet` in code, consider storing them under a key that combines `gameType` and `bet`:

```
{
  'gameRequests': {
    'nhl_10': {
      '1': {
        createdAt: 1454777718074,
        uid: 123,
      },
      '3': {
        createdAt: 1454777718076,
        uid: 321,
      }
    },
    'nhl_20': {
      '2': {
        createdAt: 1454777718075,
        uid: 123,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you code becomes:

```
function onGameRequestsUpdate (snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(gametypeSnapshot) {
     if (gametypeSnapshot.numChildren() >= 2) {
       // there is at least one request pair for this game type
     }
   });
};
```

I keep recommending people to read [this article](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), since it explains [NoSQL Data Modeling techniques](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) such as this one.

Comment: Great suggestion about `id`.  Do you think it's ok to store the whole snapshot in memory? Is there a way to modify request using firebase query?

Comment: "Do you think it's ok to store the whole snapshot in memory?" Since these are games that you're trying to match, that sounds OK. If there are too many, do a [shallow REST load](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-uri-params) of the gameTypes first `http://yours.firebaseio.com/gameRequests.json?shallow=true` and then loop over the keys to handle then one game type at a time.

Comment: "Is there a way to modify request using firebase query?" Nope. You'll have to create a new request.